# wordpress "a la" drupal option for upload

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I am wordking on a site, made with wordpress, and i like to have some sort of interractivity with the reader/user. So if anyone would like to contribute to a page/post i like to have a button "contribute" and ability to send images and text

I have seen that done with drupal, but have no idea how to thame that proble with wordpress... i know that i can "force" the user to register with limited role, but registering user just to enable them to send me there "best" cat picture seem overkill..

solution ?, experience, you have done it successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you search on WordPress plugin repository ?

Maybe this one has the feature you want : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-video-pack/